# Grails 3 - Spring security OAuth2 provider - custom security provider is ignored

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

My configuration is:

- Grails framework 3.0.11
- "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3"
- "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-provider:3.0.0-RC1"

I have specified my custom UserDetailsService (implementing GrailsUserDetailsService), custom User Details class (extending GrailsUser) and also custom security authentication provider (extending AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider).

I have placed it to *resources.groovy* as follows:

```
userDetailsService(My2nUserDetailsService)

my2nAuthenticationProvider(My2nAuthenticationProvider) {
    userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
}
```

Now my problem is that when I want to send POST to **/oauth/token** so my custom provider (**my2nAuthenticationProvider**) is ignored and default *daoAuthenticationProvider* is used and it fails because this provider calls default User Details Service (so again... my custom My2nUserDetailsService is ignored) and everything fails.

This is how I configured Spring Security core and Spring Security Oauth2 provider:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'cz.quanti.my2n.domains.my2n.My2nUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'cz.quanti.my2n.domains.my2n.My2nUserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'cz.quanti.my2n.domains.my2n.My2nRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'InterceptUrlMap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'SHA-256'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations = 1
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
        'my2nAuthenticationProvider'
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/oauth/authorize.dispatch', access: "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"],
    [pattern: '/oauth/token.dispatch', access: "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"]
]

// https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/filters.html
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
            [pattern: '/oauth/token', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
            [pattern: '/oauth/authorize', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter'],
            ...
            [pattern: '/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter']   // Traditional chain
    ]

// Added by the Spring Security OAuth2 Provider plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.clientLookup.className = 'cz.quanti.my2n.domains.hipmo.OauthClient'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorizationCodeLookup.className = 'cz.quanti.my2n.domains.hipmo.OauthAuthorizationCode'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.accessTokenLookup.className = 'cz.quanti.my2n.domains.hipmo.OauthAccessToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.refreshTokenLookup.className = 'cz.quanti.my2n.domains.hipmo.OauthRefreshToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorization.requireScope = false
```

Can you give me some advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that plugin, but if you want your bean registration to replace the one registered by a plugin you need to use the same bean name in resources.groovy. From looking at the plugin source I assume you want to replace the `clientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider` bean, so your provider registration should look like

```
clientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider(My2nAuthenticationProvider) {
   userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
```

}

Comment: The problem is that there is no bean named "clientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider" within that versions I have mentioned in my post.

Comment: It is specified here http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/v3/manual/guide/introduction.html (change log for version 2.0-RC5)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring securityConfigType as "InterceptUrlMap", yet you use controllerAnnotations for mapping. Update securityConfigType to use "Annotation"